# How to hide body border in IE when <!DOCTYPE html> is used?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, border, margin, doctype

I have a page with nothing inside but this CSS:

```
body
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px;
    background-color:black;
}
```

It is supposed to hide all borders on the page.

When I use !DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" or don't use DOCTYPE at all, it works fine in all browsers. When I use !DOCTYPE html, it works in all browsers but IE.

Any ideas why?

Update: I'm not sure why but I don't see borders on the production site, only locally. The code is the same here and there...

Comment: I suspect you might be seeing the effects of margins on child elements poking outside the body. It is hard to tell without a test case that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured. My IE was running in compatibility mode for local site.

Comment: You post questions here to ask for help from others. But when you found the solution you are to lazy to help others! How did you turn off compatibility mode for local sites? A little more explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

instead of body use *

```
* {

    border: 0px;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately this didn't make any difference.

Comment: I figured. My IE was running in compatibility mode for local site.